# Test connection availability on window online event - javascript

Tags: javascript, connection

I have a function that listens to window online event, and should perform a dummy speed test to see if I'm actually online or not. Now, the problem is, it fails sometimes, even if the connection is working fine. The code looks something like this

```
window.addEventListener("online", async function () {
// some code here
try {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  options.signal = controller.signal;
  return Promise.race([
    fetch(url, options),
    new Promise((_, reject) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        controller.abort();
        reject(new Error("timeout"));
      }, timeout)
    )
  ]);
} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err);
  return null;
}
})
```

where url is a test url we thrust, the method is a simple POST with a 10kb dummy json body.

Now the problem is, sometimes when switching, the test will go on timeout, even if the data is that small. The timeout is set to just a bit more than a second as of now. We don't want to raise the timeout too much, but I'm wondering if there's a safe delay to use that is not too large? Is there a certain timespan to wait before doing a speed test once online (because of network instability/unavailability)?